# How to get the last time a particular file was downloaded from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was wondering if there is a way to get the last downloaded time on of an S3 object.
I had a use case where I need this data to decide whether to remove a file if its not downloaded for a set period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to access this information is by enabling logging on the bucket, and then setting up a script to parse the logs and possibly storing the history in a database.  In my use case, we use these logs to do analytics as well as to identify 404 errors that might mean users are experiencing broken links or images.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/ManagingBucketLogging.html